# How can I construct a nilpotent matrix of order 100 and index 98?

Tags: matrices, examples-counterexamples, nilpotence

I know to construct a nilpotent matrix of order $n$ with index of nilpotency $n$, but how to construct a nilpotent matrix of order $n$ but index of nilpotency $(n-2)$? Is there any general rule for the same?

Comment: I meant the index of nilpotency of the matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer gives you a very general hint on how to tackle the problem. It can be narrowed to your problem.

Let say we want to construct a matrix of order $m$ and index $n$ ($m\ge n$). The most simple nilpotent matrix having order equal to the index is the one having $1$ on the upper (or under, but this is not the usual form) diagonal, for example with order (and index) $4$ :

$$J = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &0 &1&0\\ 0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Geometrically, if we take the canonical basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$, we project $e_4$ into $e_3$, $e_3$ into $e_2$, $e_2$ in to $e_1$ and $e_1$ into $0$. Thus $e_4$ will be projected to $0$ at the $4$-th application of $J$ and is the last one.  This kind of matrix is known as Jordan's matrix.

Following the hint given in the other answer, the block matrix $\begin{bmatrix} J &\mathbf{0}\\\mathbf{0}^T&0 \end{bmatrix}$, where $\mathbf{0}$ is a zero vector of compatible size (4 elements in this case) , has the same index than $J$, thus $4$, but has order $5$.

Based on this, we are able to construct a matrix with index $4$ and arbitrary order $\ge4$. Can you generalize the idea ?

Comment: Thank you I got it. I couldn't work with the hint because I am not aware of direct sum of matrices to say the least. Can you also give a good source, if you know to self-study the concept so that I can understand it the next time it pops-up anywhere. :)

Comment: I only worked with books in my mother tongue to learn this. If you are ok with French I sure can. The block defined matrix in this answer is basically the direct sum of $J$ and the zero matrix of order $1$, basically it means that there is no "interactions" between the two matrix you are summing.

Comment: Don't know French unfortunately. I will google the concept.

Comment: Those are pretty basic linear algebra concepts. Wikipedia already provides a lot of informations about them. Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $A_1$ is a nilpotent matrix of order $n_1$ and index $k_1$, and $A_2$ is a nilpotent matrix of order $n_2$ and index $k_2$, then their direct sum $A_1\oplus A_2$ is a nilpotent matrix of order ? and index ?

Comment: I think this is a little too general for the question asked. It is enough to take $A_2$ as a zero matrix (with carefully chosen sizes for this one and $A_1$) in this case.

Comment: @nicomezi You're right. On the other hand, OP also asked for "any general rule" which is a pretty broad license :)

Comment: As far as I understand, I read it as a "general rule" to construct a nilpotent matrix with given order and index, so I maintain my remark.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. But pardon my lack of awareness being a newbie. Can you please elaborate on your hint, an example to make things easier would be great.

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha Okay, for example if $A_1$ is a nilpotent matrix of order $4$ and index $3$, and $A_2$ is a nilpotent matrix of order $5$ and index $2$, then their direct sum $A_1\oplus A_2$ is a nilpotent matrix of order ? and index ?